# Classification problem: estimate the number of people in a household through account transactions

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I want to estimate how many people are in a household by looking at account transactions. It would be also interesting to understand if in the household there are children.

I thought that a possible way to proceed could be to compare the living expenses with that of the average individual according to the national statistics. Moreover I could also perform text analytics to retrieve informations about what products people bought (in order to understand if they spent money to buy children products).

As model I could maybe use a random forest for classification (but please correct me if I'm wrong).

Are there better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think regression makes more sense here than classification; you are trying to predict a number. In particular I would recommend [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) since you are modeling count data. Software is readily available for various languages.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a nice idea, but I don't think that could be a general solution to the problem. The output in this case should follow a Poisson distribution and I don't think that in this sense account transactions always respect [all the assumptions of the Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Assumptions:_When_is_the_Poisson_distribution_an_appropriate_model.3F)

Comment: All models are wrong; some are useful. [Household size and the poisson distribution](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41110478)